# Highchart stacking highest bar to combine the rest

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, highcharts

I want to use the stacking so that it takes the highest value as the longest column/bar and the smaller ones are merged in the highest bar.
In the example : Arsenal has 2 values : 14 and 3. in the stack chart it shows 17 and shows the 2 bars on top of each other. what i want is these stacks to merge and show maximum 14 number as the large bar and 3 number is stacked within 14 so that y axis should not cross the highest bar value in any case.
Similarly for liverpool values are 6,8 and 1. so it should should have maximum of y axis value as 8(i dont need the sum of the values)
Is there a possibility for this?

[https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-stacked]

Y axis to show the value of maximum number in the series and not the sum of all the stacked columns.[image]
***Update:***

[https://jsfiddle.net/vkcg9mfo/]

In this fiddle you will see i was able to achieve this for manchester but it is not correct for arsenal and others as it hides the lower value stacks. All 3 colors should be visible for all the stacks in the bars.
Expected:
[image]

***UPDATED ANSWER:***
[https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9n1cqe2x/]

Comment: So at the end you want to achieve something that looks like this: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hzvk4q0s/?

Comment: No. it should be the same stacked graph as shown in the question . its just the stacking should be merged or combined. As explained if the there are 3 stacks(values 3,12 and 13) for one category(ex Manchester) then all the bars should be shown in stacking but the lower values which in this case will be 3,12 should me merged in the bigger value stack. I am adding expected result in the question. Y axis will be 13 and showing all 3 stacks with one bar.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Highcharts do not have this type of charts. This is not staking, at least not in the traditional sense of the word.

You can use the `pointPlacement` property on series to make them overlap, but then you need to sort them appropriately so that the highest values are in one series and the series are sorted in descending order so that smaller columns are not hidden under larger ones:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    series: [{
        data: [14, 8, 8, 13],
        pointPlacement: 0.2
    }, {
        data: [3, 5, 6, 12],
        pointPlacement: 0
    }, {
        data: [0, 2, 1, 3],
        pointPlacement: -0.2
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zqvma6wb/ 
**API**: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.pointPlacement

Comment: Hello Thank you for the answer. i have tried this approach but didn't really help but i was able to do this kind of overlapping (thanks to Highcharts team) :
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9n1cqe2x/

Comment: Hello,
I have negative values as well in the chart and i cannot see yellow value bars which are negative values. i think its probably because of the sorting. Could you please check and see whats wrong?
https://jsfiddle.net/sahil_vig/v47bseLd/7

Comment: For negative values, you should sort the data in the opposite way than for positive values.